# Dictionary comprehension using *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python. I have to do a little exercise. I have two classes RealNumber and ComplexNumber and I need to create a new class, with, as an attribute, a dictionary (dict_number) that contains an integer as a key and a RealNumber or ComplexNumber object as value. In the **init** method, with parameters *args and **kwargs, each arg in *args must be entered with an increasing integer key (using the dict comprehension) (e.g. {0: RealNumber0, 1: RealNumber1, 2: ComplexNumber0}) while for each arg in kwargs it will be necessary to insert the parameter name: value.
Now, I have already created the classes RealNumber and ComplexNumber, but I'm having issues doing the third class.
How can I create a dict that have an incremental value as key and a tuple (object name, object value) as value?
The dictionary must have this form: `{incremental key: (name_object, object value)}` ,  for example: `{0: Realnumber 5, 1: ComplexNumber 1+3i...}` Where `0:` is the incremental key; `Realnumber` is the name of the object class; `5` is the value contained by the `Realnumber` class object.

```
...

class NumbersCollection:  # I've issues here
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.dict_numbers = {key: arg for key, arg in kwargs.items()} 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = RealNumber(5)
    y = ComplexNumber(1, 3) #first parameter is the real part, the 2nd is the imaginary part

    print(f"Number: {x.number}")
    print(f"RealPart: {y.numPart}, ImPart: {y.imPart}")

    d = NumbersCollection(a=x, b=y) # I've issues here

...
```

Comment: What's the point of `self.dict_numbers = {key: arg for key, arg in kwargs.items()}`, whenver you see `{k:v for k,v in whatever}`, you really just want `dict(whatever)`, so `self.dict_numbers = dict(kwargs)`, but what's the point of that in this case? Why not just `self.dict_numbers = kwargs`? `kwargs` will always be a new dict object anyway

Comment: `kwargs` is already a dictionary. So you can assign that directly.

Comment: Use `enumerate(args)` to loop through the arguments with a counter alongside it.

Comment: In any case, it really isn't clear what you are asking

Comment: the dictionary must have this form: `{incremental key: (name_object, object value)}` ,  for example: `{0: Realnumber 4, 1: ComplexNumber 12+2i...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, you are asking too many questions in a single question. So there is another answer.

#### `__repr__`

You can modify `representation` of an object of a class defining `__repr__` method on a class:

```py
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"SomeClass {self.value}"
```

```py
>>> SomeClass(1)
SomeClass 1
```

#### `enumerate`

You can use `enumerate` function on an iterable to iterate objects in a sequence, returning `index` as first value and `value` of an object as second value

```py
data = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
}
```

```py
>>> for i, (key, value) in enumerate(data.items()):
...     print(i, key, value)
...
0 a 1
1 b 2
2 c 3
```

#### Answering your question,

combine this techniques to get the desired answer.

Using `__repr__`:

```py
class RealNumber:
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"RealNumber {self.value}"


class ComplexNumber:
    def __init__(self, value: int, imaginary_part: int) -> None:
        self.real_part = value
        self.imaginary_part = imaginary_part

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ComplexNumber {self.real_part}+{self.imaginary_part}i"
```

Using `enumerate`:

```py
class NumbersCollection:
    def __init__(self, *args: Union[RealNumber, ComplexNumber]):
        self.dict_numbers = dict(enumerate(args))
```

The use of dictionary comprehension there is not required as `dict(enumerate(args))` does the same, but better and cleaner. You can, of course, use them if it is a requirement of your assignment.

```py
class NumbersCollection:
    def __init__(self, *args: Union[RealNumber, ComplexNumber]):
        self.dict_numbers = {i: value for i, value in enumerate(args)}
```

Both should produce the same answer.

```py
>>> nums = NumbersCollection(RealNumber(1), ComplexNumber(1, 2))
>>> nums.dict_numbers
{0: RealNumber 1, 1: ComplexNumber 1+2i}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `from typing import Union`

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution, even if I don't know if the lack of the **kwargs parameter would be okay according to the text.

Comment: @Argo2007 let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```py
class NumbersCollection:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.dict_numbers = {
            i: (key, value) for i, (key, value) in enumerate(kwargs.items())
        }
```

```py
>>> nums = NumbersCollection(a=1, b=2)
>>> nums.dict_numbers
{0: ('a', 1), 1: ('b', 2)}
```

Comment: The text of the exercise forces to use *args and **kwargs

Comment: @Argo2007 I don't really see how can you utilize both `*args` and `**kwargs` in this example.

Comment: So do I, but the teacher gave this text.